# Spring Gutter Icons not shown in Intellij IDEA 2018.2 Ultimate

Tags: intellij-idea

In IDEA 2018.1 ultimate I can see the gutter icons without any issue. Same icons are not available in IDEA 2018.2.

Are there any new settings I should take care of?

Comment: Check that you do not have File | Power Safe Mode enabled. The settings for gutter icons are under Settings(Preferences) | Editor | General | Gutter Icons - check that they are enabled there.

Comment: Also check that you have Spring facet with the Spring Context configured for the project https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/spring-support.html#configure-spring-project-facet

Comment: Same problem here. I tested it with 2018.2.2 and 2018.2.3 EAP. I have everything set up correctly and no gutter icons appear. I've installed 2018.1.6, just for testing, and it worked fine.

Comment: Issue resolved by updating intellij to latest stable release